Jupyter notebook cell become half width automatically when I got for edit

I worked on this notebook before now when I open and start editing or click on it before editing cell width becomes half (cell 2). However I didn't click cell 3 it's normal, if I click on it it will become half-width cell. Any suggestion please?
The above changes are irrespective of Python version and noticed in Jupyterlab too.
